# List of 'messed up characters' in utf8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

one of my clients has a website which has been totally messed up by the hosting companie forcing a characterset on the complete database. We've had troubles before with character sets but now it's just straight forward a drama!

So far I've added the charset=utf-8 to the page content type and set the charset for the mysql connection to utf8. And now it's time to replace all characters. So far what I've found is:

```
Ã¶ = ö
Ã« = ë
Ã© = é
```

The data inside the database is being updated like so:

```
UPDATE table SET `fieldname` = REPLACE(`fieldname`, 'Ã¶', 'ö');
```

Now I just need to find a complete list of alle characters that are messed up. I tried a MySQL query searching for `field LIKE '%Ã%'` but this returns me all records inside the database.

Google also just displays a couple of characters (mostly the 3 above) in some topics of other people that have had troubles, however it seems there's nowhere a complete list of these characters (or at least the most common) which I can use to find and replace all data for my client.

If anyone perhaps knows such location or is able to complete my list I will, in return, create a page containing these characters to help others (unless there's a list already which I'm not aware of somewhere ofcourse).

// `EDIT`:

it would be for the most common european characters such as é è ë, á à ä, ö ó ò, ï, ü and perhaps the ringel-S (German double S). Not so much for the spaning signs like ñ or ã, but if they are in a list somewhere that would be much appreciated aswel.

// `EDIT 2`:

I updated the MySQL database and tables using the 2 ALTER queries from the 1st part of this article: `http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet`. I DID NOT make use of the mb_ functions so far and didn't do any MB configuration as it seems.

The headers are all set to utf-8 in the files (I still have to check the headers for some ajax scripts tho, not sure if that's needed but it won't be harmfull doing so). And the files are all saved as UTF8 without BOM. Also PHPFreakMailer is updated by setting the charset to utf-8.

`Bad enough`, I'm still having these weird characters. I wasn't thinking they'd go away by theirself, but at least it was worth hoping so :-) So what's the final step I should take? Continuïng using the REPLACE query and changing all wierd characters manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not force the tables and connection to the charset you need? Not that doing so would actually *solve* the real problem though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit crazy; what character set do you think "Ã¶" is in?

It looks like that's actually a correct UTF-8 sequence (since it's two bytes), you're just displaying it as ISO-8559-1.

**Edit**:

Based on your comment I think the following is going on:

I *think* (but really not 100% sure) that the correct UTF-8 binary sequence is stored in the database. But since the table is marked as ISO-8559-1, and you requested to automatically convert character set. So it thinks it's ISO-8559-1 (which looks like Ã¶), but then tries to convert that to UTF-8.

You should be able to verify this, if strlen('Ã¶') is 4, and not 2. If the length is indeed 2, your browser encoding somehow screws up.

To fix this, don't set the MySQL to encode the characters.

**Option 2**

The data could also be 'double encoded' in the table. To check this, simply also check the string length on the database. If the 'Ã¶' is 4 bytes long, this is the issue.

My advice in this case is to not try to make a big 'messed up character'-map. You should simply be able to 'utf8_decode' the string. Normally this function will output a ISO-8559-1 string, but in your case.. it should turn out to be the original valid UTF-8 string.

I hope this works!

**Edit2**

Ok so effectively what I believe has happened is Option 2. To put it in simple (php) terms:

```
$output = utf8_encode(utf8_encode('string'));
```

So one utf8_decode() should be enough.

Do test this before you run your migration scripts though :)

Comment: I've set the DB character set to utf8 according to `http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet` what other steps should I take? I noticed still some old characters are displayed as Ã« which I guess is because this data was saved using ISO headers. Is the replace query I mentioned in my post is the right way to convert them all back?

Comment: Check my original suggestion. First find out how long those 'weird' characters are. If they are indeed twice as long as you expect (4 instead of 2) your characters are double encoded.

Comment: Ok, it says strlen() = 4, is replacing all characters in the database a valid option aswell? Since I want to to run properly in the future aswel, so saving the data as it SHOULD be would by my best solution.

Comment: Great, so I'm actually thinking now 'Option 2' is the most likely scenario. To get back to your original data, simply do a conversion from 'UTF-8' to 'ISO-8559-1'. The output *will* be UTF-8 anyway.

Comment: And how should I do this? Aren't the REPLACE queries basically doing the same thing in just another way? (Replacing double encoded data with single encoded?)

Comment: Yes technically it's the same. However, php's utf8_decode does this work for you. What you're asking is how to write a UTF-8 to ISO-8559-1 decoder. My answer is: don't write it yourself, it's silly.

Comment: So if I'd create a PHP script that reads all data from a table, runs utf8_decode over the value and inserts it back into the database, that would solve the problem? Then the last question is, if you see the post from Berry Langerak, do I still need to update each column to utf8+utf8_general_ci (I guess I should..)?

Comment: I added another edit explaining it even simpler. But yes, if your columns are marked latin1, it's wise to change this back to UTF-8. However, you need to make sure that MySQL does not do any conversion, since you're already going to do this yourself.

Comment: Okay, here we go backing up the database and changing the charset+collate for each column and see what happens after that :-) *fingers crossed*

Comment: Yes, well that won't fix it:) you still need to do the conversion. If MySQL converts from Latin1 to UTF-8 it also means your characters are now triple-encoded and 8 bytes long.

Comment: So my steps would be (1) converting columns to utf8. (2) reading a record with messed up data from the DB and see the strlen() of a weird character (3) look what happens with strlen() after each utf8_decode.

Comment: Last question (I hope)! All other characters (like a,b,c,d,e etc) are they still the same 'bytesize' as they need to be? Or will they also become larger?

Comment: Every ASCII character has the same respresentation in ISO-8559-1 / latin and in UTF-8. The special characters should be 1 byte in ISO-8559-1, and 2 bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: Ok, got some things tested. At first I ran a query on a record which I knew had some false characters. Fetchting the data using the latin1/iso charset and running utf8_decode() over this string gave me the right result after 1 time utf8_decode(). After converting this table to utf8/utf8_general_ci, the result was exact the same. However(!) if the result was already decoded, then decoding it would cause question marks instead of the right characters. So I think I'm still left with having to replace them using the query I used before.

Comment: This makes sense. If it was already decoded utf8_decode will fail.

Comment: it can be that some parts have been decoded already yes, I've got no clue what happend with the charset and what data has been inserted using what charset. But you would agree with me that my best shot on solving this is to use the REPLACE query mentioned in the question? And that after this the data should be in the right format? If so, then I'm gonna do that now and +1 everyone's help and accept your answer :)

Comment: I also told the client to take a close watch on strange characters, most of 'm seem fine now and if they see any it must be some rarely used characters which they then have to replace by hand using the adminpanel I programmed for them. As it all seems to work right now, +1 for the help and since you helped out the most I'll accept your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If they forced a character change, why is your database not converted? Are your tables still the old character set (see your phpMyAdmin on table information).

Is the data wrong if it shows up in your phpMyAdmin or only on your webpage? -> your names and collation should change, as well as headers and filetype (safe file as utf-8).

Or try:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I would start replacing characters only if there are no options from within MySQL left.

Comment: Ok ok, both in PHPMyAdmin and on the webpage the characters where displayed as 'Ã¶', so both of them displayed the strange character. The webpage having utf8 headers, charset and a utf8 mysql connection. The database has 'character_set_database' on 'latin1'. My biggest fear is that changing the charset in the database will cause all the data to be messed up again, or is there's no chance this happens?

Comment: I updated the charset & collation of the database, but these characters still display badly because they are probably saved/converted to the ISO displayed characters (I wouldn't know what else happened..) so I guess I should still use my method to convert all odd characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. +1 for your time and thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this question with "php", I assume you read the database and it's values with PHP? If so, please have a look at [mb_convert_encoding](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) if you no longer have control over the database.

The better solution would be to fix the inconsistency between the data and the tables characterset. Backup the database (just in case), and alter all tables *and* columns to UTF-8. **Note**: when using MySQL, it is **not enough** to alter the table's charset, you'll have to do this per column.

Comment: thanks for the warning, I noticed the columns still having latin1 collation and I guess still utf8 charset aswel. Is this the right query I need? `ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`? I'd better write myself a script that does this for each column then.

Comment: Yep. That script is probably roaming on the internet as well, so you don't necessarily have to write it.

Comment: I guess making a backup wouldn't be a to bad either before running this.

Comment: Ok, I found this piece at serverfault.com: `http://serverfault.com/questions/65043/alter-charset-and-collation-in-all-columns-in-all-tables-in-mysql`. There's a query: `SELECT distinct CONCAT( 'alter table ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, '  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;' ) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DBname';` that seems to be doing what I need?

Comment: That should get you the query. And indeed, make sure to make a backup first! Also, if you have the chance, don't do this on the live database, do it on a test database first!

Comment: too bad, this query just gives me the ALTER queries for the tables not for the colums.

Comment: Thanks for the help. +1 for your time and thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use: `&auml; = ä`, `&ouml; = ö`,...

Do `htmlentities();` in php and it will convert all special characters into Entitys. 
I think this would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: this would be too much work since a lot of data is already crippled by the changing datasets from the hosting provider. I have to get the current characters fixed if that's done I don't believe using htmlentities() is neccesary since all charsets are the same (and thus saving them to and reading them from the database shouldn't be a problem). Thanks for your thinking tho!